# Is there an intuitive explanation for the equality of mixed partials?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative, intuition

The fact that the mixed second order partial derivatives of a $C^2$ smooth scalar valued function are equal seems, to me, quite surprising. For example, if you interpret $\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial y \partial x}$ as the change of the slope of a tangent line along the $x$-axis when moving along the $y$-axis, it's not at all obvious to me that this should equal $\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x \partial y}$.

Does there exist some intuitive or visual way to explain this equality? Just to be clear, I'm not looking for a formal proof (this can be found in most textbooks), but some intuitive reason or hint as to why this might be true.

Comment: A nice smooth function ought to have a tangent quadric (just as it has a tangent plane) at each point, that is $f(x,y)=a+bx+cy+rx^2+sxy+ty^2+o(\|(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)\|^2)$ near $(x_0,y_0)$. The second partials at $(x_0,y_0)$ of the little o-term should vanish, and the mixed second partials of the polynomial part are certainly equal.

Comment: isn't it basically some kind of two-dimensional mean value theorem?  some sort of "difference quotient" (which is somehow symmetrical in x and y) of the values of the function at the corners of a square has to be equal to the second partial(s) somewhere (two different points) in the square.  So you can squeeze the square to a point and use continuity of the second derivatives

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One intuition is that if the function is smooth enough then it is well approximated by its *second degree* Taylor polynomial, and equality of mixed partials is straightforward for those polynomials.

Let's focus on just two variables; nothing really changes if there are more. An arbitrary quadratic in $x$ and $y$ looks like
$$
q(x,y) = a + bx + cy + dx^2 + exy + fy^2
$$

If we compute $(\partial^2 q)/(\partial x \partial y)$ we obtain $e$, and if we compute $(\partial^2 q)/(\partial y \partial x)$ we also obtain $e$. So in this special case the mixed partials are equal.

If $f(x,y)$ is smooth enough, it is well approximated by its Taylor polynomials. For example, the first-degree Taylor polynomial is the equation of the tangent plane at a given point, and this first-degree polynomial agrees with $f$ on the first partial derivatives.  If $f$ is smooth enough, the second-degree Taylor polynomial gives a quadratic function in $x$ and $y$ that agrees with the first and second derivatives. In particular, this means the mixed second partials of $f$ will be equal.

In the special case where we have a second-degree Taylor polynomial of a function $f(x,y)$ at the point $(0,0)$, the polynomial has this form:
$$
\begin{split}
p(x,y) &= f(0,0) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Big |_{(0,0)}\cdot x +\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Big |_{(0,0)}\cdot y\\
& + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\Big |_{(0,0)}\cdot \frac{x^2}{2}+ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}\Big |_{(0,0)}\cdot xy + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\Big |_{(0,0)}\cdot \frac{y^2}{2}    
\end{split}
$$